# Jetpack Compose: Make offset image outside parent visible

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I added an image inside a card with a background color and I want some part of my image to overflow outside the container and be visible. I used `offset` to offset the image but I can’t find the way to make it visible.

Here’s my code:

```
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(),
    backgroundColor = Color.Cyan,
    onClick = {},
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight()) {

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(250.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.TopEnd)
                .offset(y = -75.dp, x = 50.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_pray),
            contentDescription = null,
        )
        Column(

        ) {}
    }
}
```

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Card` is based on Material surface, and it's [using](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/a9ab69a9190c3e6352c3d0b0f96c3b1f0fccb2b5/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Surface.kt#L264) [`Modifier.clip`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clip(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape)) which prevent your offset view from being displayed.

If you need to maintain `Card` elevation, you can place the image in a `Box` outside of `Card`:

```
Box {
    Card(...)
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(250.dp)
            .align(alignment = Alignment.TopEnd)
            .offset(y = -75.dp, x = 50.dp),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_image),
        contentDescription = null,
    )
}
```

Otherwise you can skip using `Card` at the first place, and set background and shape to your `Box` with [`Modifier.background`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).background(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape)):

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .background(Color.Cyan, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight()) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(250.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.TopEnd)
                .offset(y = -75.dp, x = 50.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_image),
            contentDescription = null,
        )
        Column(

        ) {}
    }
}
```